# Disabling all tasks with schtasks

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I need to do a batch file who disables all tasks, so far i've gotten this:

```
@echo OFF
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i  in ('schtasks /Query /FO LIST ^| findstr "Nombre de tarea:"') do (call :subroutine "%%i")

:subroutine
set TASKNAME=%%i
echo %TASKNAME%:%1
schtasks /change /tn=%TASKNAME%:%1 /disable
GOTO :eof
```

so, im pretty bad with grep, its been 2 years without having to use it, this is what "findstr" "spits":

```
 %i:" Interactivo/En segundo plano"
 %i:" ADMSH-PC"
 %i:" \Microsoft\Windows\Windows Media Sharing\UpdateLibrary"
```

so i get 3 rows per task and also i only need the "task name" for the tn property instead of the whole path

Any help/tips? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in (
    'schtasks /Query /FO csv ^| find /V "Task name" ^| find /V "Disabled"'
) do (
    schtasks /change /tn %%a /disable
)
```

Note: If you show a sample of this command '`schtasks /Query /FO csv`' I can edit the command to your locale

Comment: "Nombre de tarea","Hora próxima ejecución","Estado"
"\Microsoft\Windows\Time Synchronization\SynchronizeTime","18/10/2015 1:00:00","
Listo"

Comment: Im also testing it, wouldnt it be find /V "Enabled"?

Comment: Its working, just had to run it as admin. Thank you Paul!

Answer (score 0):

If you are disabling all tasks would it not be easier to just stop the Task Scheduler Service?

Answer (score 0):

Good point, however if you want to disable them I'd suggest putting your script into a vbs file:

You could list all tasks with this code :

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colScheduledJobs = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_ScheduledJob")
For Each objJob in colScheduledJobs
    Wscript.Echo "Caption: " & objJob.Caption
    Wscript.Echo "Command: " & objJob.Command
    Wscript.Echo "Days Of Month: " & objJob.DaysOfMonth
    Wscript.Echo "Days Of Week: " & objJob.DaysOfWeek
    Wscript.Echo "Description: " & objJob.Description
    Wscript.Echo "Elapsed Time: " & objJob.ElapsedTime
    Wscript.Echo "Install Date: " & objJob.InstallDate
    Wscript.Echo "Interact with Desktop: " & objJob.InteractWithDesktop
    Wscript.Echo "Job ID: " & objJob.JobID
    Wscript.Echo "Job Status: " & objJob.JobStatus
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objJob.Name
    Wscript.Echo "Notify: " & objJob.Notify
    Wscript.Echo "Owner: " & objJob.Owner
    Wscript.Echo "Priority: " & objJob.Priority
    Wscript.Echo "Run Repeatedly: " & objJob.RunRepeatedly
    Wscript.Echo "Start Time: " & objJob.StartTime
    Wscript.Echo "Status: " & objJob.Status
    Wscript.Echo "Time Submitted: " & objJob.TimeSubmitted
    Wscript.Echo "Until Time: " & objJob.UntilTime
Next
```

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/09/22/how-can-i-manage-scheduled-tasks-using-scripts.aspx

Grab the name of all tasks and run a `schtasks /change /tn=%TASKNAME%:%1` /disable for each.

Comment: If i could use vs or c# i would be using Wscript like you suggested, but i've been ordered to achieve it only by plain batch, so they can execute it in a simple .bat,  Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Why disable the tasks? Stop and start the Task Schedule service from the command line. If Stop is greyed out in Services - Task Scheduler download [PsTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) and:

Run as administrator:

```
PSEXEC -i -s CMD
```

In the CMD window:

```
net stop schedule
```

When you are ready:

```
net start schedule
```

Enable Disable all Scheduled Tasks Enable Disable all Tasks Task Scheduler stop greyed out